# Atom editor giving me "Could not bind socket" error with php-debug

Tags: docker, atom-editor, xdebug

I have successfully setup Atom + php-debug + Docker by using my local machine's IP address.

However, I learnt that Docker for Mac has `docker.for.mac.host.internal` so I don't have to keep finding my local IP.

When I change my Atom php-debug settings to use the host name, it gives me the error message:

`Could not bind socket, do you already have an instance of the debugger open?`

Can anyone offer some suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide: 1) your xdebug version; 2) your xdebug config (where you have put that `docker.for.mac.host.internal` value) 3) xdebug log for such failed debug session (it should tell where it tries to connect etc)

Comment: @LazyOne - I don't think this is an issue with xdebug but here's the info you requested:

```
xdebug.idekey=xdebug-atom
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.host.internal
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```

http://shot.taylor.kiwi.nz/3m0a0f380M33

xdebug version 2.5.0

I haven't done the logs, but will try and get them to you

Comment: Xdebug log output:

Log opened at 2018-03-19 15:35:43
I: Connecting to configured address/port: docker.for.mac.host.internal:9000.
W: Creating socket for 'docker.for.mac.host.internal:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-03-19 15:35:43

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to NOT set `docker.for.mac.host.internal` in Atom, but leave it default to `127.0.0.1`